# How to display date in the column header in single day view?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-3

In fullcalendar scheduler, it display date name of each day in the column header (first row, the second one are resources), but it disappear when the view is on single day.

I want to display in the single day, the first row with date name, the same as in multiple days, because I don't display title in header of fullcalendar.

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to enable this unfortunately. Perhaps you should raise a feature request with the fullCalendar maintainers to allow an option to show it in the timeline view. https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I get this https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-scheduler/issues/368

Answer (score 0):

here you can check the solution:

> you can do this with using jquery on click event on day button

[fullcalendar-change-header-title-text-in-single-day-view](https://therichpost.com/fullcalendar-change-header-title-text-in-single-day-view)

Comment: did you check on my blog link?